# Good approaches for processing xml in C++

Tags: c++, xml, message

I work on a multithreaded message processing application written in C++.  The application receives xml messages, performs some action, and may publish out an xml message to another service if required.

Currently, the app works by extracting data while parsing the message and performing some action on that message in the middle of parsing.  This seems like poor practice to me.  I have the opportunity to create an alternative, and I'm considering approaches I can use.

One method I've thought of is to serialize the xml data into a data object, and once that is finished, extract and process data as needed.  The disadvantage would be that I have to build a new class for each different xml message I process (probably around 30), but that approach seems cleaner than what I have now.

Is there a better way than this?  Should also mention the caveat that any code libraries developed outside the U.S. are unlikely to be approved.

Comment: Where does this "non-U.S" code rule come from ? There are a lot of good libraries developped all around the world: having to use only those written on the U.S ground seems really weird.

Comment: This is a stipulation from the government customer.

Comment: it might be cheaper to use non-US code but use a copy pegged to a particular version, and audit it before including it in your code base (and audit each time when updating to a new version). Although auditing takes time, it's probably going to take less time than implementing it yourself. (That is, assuming you can convince your government customer that auditing it in this way is sufficient).

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, the app works

Then what exactly are you fixing?

Don't fix what isn't broken.

Comment: "If it's not broken, it doesn't have enough features." ^^

Comment: @Zeta, the OP explicitly states it's an opportunity to create an alternative - sounds like a government IT project.. ;)

Comment: what about refactoring? Is it a bug the only reason to change a software? The application is parsing and executing actions at the same time. This create an artificial dependency between two distinct processes, it can be very hard handle exceptions properly and also it will limit the reuse of the code in future. At the end the right decision may still be to do nothing, however in my opinion it is worth the effort to think about it.

Comment: @Alessandro, this is exactly right.  The dependency you mention is what doesn't sit right with me and I'm looking for architectural advice for a refactor.

Answer (score 1):

There are typically two approaches to XML parsing: DOM and SAX. DOM builds up a document object model (like what you are proposing), whereas SAX invokes callbacks as parts of the document are visited during parsing. The free, well-known [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) library supports both parsing methods.

Typically, the SAX approach (i.e., using callbacks that get executed as the document is visited), uses less memory and can result in lower end-user latency, because you can start processing immediately, instead of having to wait for the entire document to have been parsed and built up.

The fact that your program is multithreaded is a red-herring. As long as you always pass an object to each of your callbacks, and that object is not shared between threads, you can safely do this with multiple different such objects in multiple different threads. Using a standard library such as libxml2 to do your parsing is also sensible from a reuse perspective.

Comment: (There are also 'pull' APIs for XML that are growing in popularity, starting with kxml that turned up around the year 2000) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX

Comment: Nice answer but the OP can't use "non U.S" code and unfortunately, [Daniel Veillard](http://veillard.com/), the author of `libxml2` is a french developper based in China.

Answer (score 1):

There were probably some design decisions that were made which led to this approach (say for example, it's faster to process using a SAX like model than a DOM like model), with the latter you need to parse the entire message, with the former you can make decisions as you are called back with data.

I'd try to understand these first before making any changes, secondly aside from keeping you busy, is there a real business need for it? If not, move on and do something else...

Comment: It's true that the app "works" and in that sense there is no "business need".  However, this app is growing and adding new features and types of messages it processes constantly.  As another poster suggested, this is a refactoring exercise where I'm attempting to provide a separation between the parsing logic and the execution logic that spawns from changes in the incoming data.  The type of processing (SAX or DOM) does not matter to me so much as a good clean architecture for this type of application.